# How to share a public photo in a group php sdk facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to share a public photo to a group using php sdk (graph api)

```
 $ret_obj = $facebook->api("/$group_id/feed", 'POST', array(
                'link' =>  $link,
                'message' => $message,
            )
        );
```

where $link is a link for the photo I want to share in this format : https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151273906386749&set=a.53081056748.66806.6815841748&type=1&theater

it didn't work so I also tried this in Graph Api Explorer,
in result i get :

```
{
  "error": {
"message": "(#100) property values must be strings or objects with a 'text' and a 'href' attribute",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 100
  }
}
```